# smtpコマンドで送った添付ファイルを受信し、添付ファイルを開きたい

Tags: postfix, openldap, dovecot

smtpコマンドで添付ファイルを送り、また受信(telnet mailsvr-01.local 110)で
受信をおこない、添付ファイルの中身を表示したいと考えてます。

まずは送信を行いました。
参照：http://d.hatena.ne.jp/shima111/20051019/p1

[root@mailcli-01 tmp]# telnet mailsvr-01.local 587
Trying 192.168.100.41...
Connected to mailsvr-01.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mailsvr-01.local ESMTP Postfix
EHLO mailsvr-01.local
250-mailsvr-01.local
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
MAIL FROM: hoge13@mailsvr-01.local
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: hoge15@mailsvr-01.local
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with .
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: hoge13@mailsvr-01.local
To: hoge15@mailsvr-01.local
Subject: aiueo
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="*1234"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-2022-JP
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-2022-JP
test111
Content-Type: text/plain; name=test.txt
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 557A5A3887

次にtelnetで110番ポートにつなぎ、受信確認をおこないました。

[root@mailsvr-01 ~]# telnet mailsvr-01.local 110
Trying 192.168.100.41...
Connected to mailsvr-01.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Dovecot ready.
USER hoge15
+OK
PASS naisyo
+OK Logged in.
LIST
+OK 36 messages:
1 754
2 411
3 749
4 749
5 749
6 756
7 747
8 745
9 752
10 747
11 418
12 415
13 409
14 409
15 409
16 430
17 430
18 430
19 430
20 430
21 430
22 430
23 346
24 428
25 428
26 428
27 428
28 659
29 714
30 714
31 667
32 667
33 667
34 667
35 667
36 666
.
RETR 36
+OK 666 octets
Return-Path: 
X-Original-To: hoge15@mailsvr-01.local
Delivered-To: hoge15@mailsvr-01.local
Received: from mailsvr-01.local (mailcli-01.local [192.168.100.40])
        by mailsvr-01.local (Postfix) with ESMTP id 557A5A3887
        for ; Fri,  8 Jan 2016 14:47:33 +0900 (JST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: hoge13@mailsvr-01.local
To: hoge15@mailsvr-01.local
Subject: aiueo
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="*1234"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-2022-JP
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-2022-JP

test111
Content-Type: text/plain; name=test.txt
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
.

①まず、添付するファイル(test.txt)が添付されて送られているのか、
②次に、受信したあとに添付のファイル(test.txt)を開く方法に関して、
ご教授いただけますでしょうか。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: そもそも送信したメールの形式が不正ですので、添付ファイルを開くもなにもありません。RFC 5322 などを読むなどして、仕様を把握しましょう。

Comment: @fumiyasさん

ありがとうございます。RFCを読んで仕様を理解します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multipart/mixed の場合は boundary で区切って異なるデータを記述する必要がありますが、DATA 以降に boundary がないので、全て 本文に書かれてる状態だと思います。
参照しているURLと比べると つぎの点が足りないですね。

- 改行が足りない
- `--*1234` の行が抜けてる
- `--*1234--` の行が抜けてる

添付ファイルを開く方法は `Return-Path:` から `.` までをテキストファイルに保存して お使いの MUA で開いてください。Thunderbird だと 拡張子を `.eml` にすれば開けます。

Comment: @take88さん

boundaryの部分を見直したら、うまく添付ファイルが送信されました。
ありがとうございます。